# Can I decompile a file if I have a compiler?

Tags: decompilation, tools, decompiler, pwntools

Is it possible to reverse the compiled code using a compiler?
I have a compiler in the form of exe and using it I can compile the file. But there is no possible instruction I got to decompile a file.
I want to know what are the possibility of getting a decompiled source code from the compiled version?
Are there any methodology or tools that would help in making it possible?
Please share your insights.

Comment: if you can add details about  the specific compiler you have, a concrete example may be easier to answer than something abstract.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky If I add the specification of the compiler, I bet no one will even care to answer in abstract ways what they are trying to answer.

Answer (score 3):

No. In most cases, you cannot obtain the actual source code just because you have the compiler available.

However, it depends on the language. If the source code was written in `.NET`, for example, a decompiler such as `dnSpy` or `ILSpy` can produce relatively accurate source code. However, if it was written in `C/C++`, for instance, then it will be harder to decompile and the decompiled result will not be as close to the original source code. Some decompilers that work for `C/C++` are `retdec` and `Ghidra`.

Comment: Is there nothing we can do in sequence that would give a clue of what is happening and what must be done?

Comment: @JafferWilson check [this](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/a/14125/60) for some options

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Thank you for sharing. I guess this is one of the wonderful ideas. I will upvote for that... :)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it's not possible.

You should use external tools like ghidra or IDAs decompiler - hex-rays.